# Checking If A Link with a unique id is being clicked multiple times in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a page with multiple links with a class of reply which have a click event associated with them.  Each link has a unique id.  Clicking the link loads a div, with content unique to that link.  What's the best best way to know if the same link is being clicked over and over again, so that I do not load the same div over and over again?

Comment: is there any chance for sharing some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/). If you are using `bind()` then you have to just add `$(this).unbind(event);`. This will make sure that link is clicked only once to load a div.

Comment: one() looks like it.  Thanks!